# Salt-Stack : adding a saltsubdirectory to top.sls

Tags: python, salt-stack

in the top.sls file, how can I declare a subdirectory ?

I would like to call those files/directory (in `top.sls`):

```
myHost salt # ls states/rcc/env_py/*
states/rcc/env_py/env.py.template  states/rcc/env_py/init.sls
```

So I added salt://states/rcc/env_py like this

```
myHost salt # cat top.sls 
base:
  '*':
    - webserver
    - salt://states/rcc/env_py
```

I had this error :

```
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    No matching sls found for 'salt://states/rcc/env_py' in env 'base'
```

after executing:

```
salt  '*' state.highstate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing:

```
salt://states/rcc/env_py
```

to

```
states/rcc/env_py/
```

resolved my problem.

Comment: You may accept your answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I should wait before, but now it's Done :-)